# Rearrange a table in Power query

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-tables

I have a table in Power Query that I'm trying to rearrange. The original table looks like this:

[image: Original]

I want to rearrange it to look like:

[image: Required]

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue. Thanks in advance!

Sara

I have noticed that if I want my desired result it would be looks like below in power query:

[image: In powwer query]

Comment: PowerQuery is designed for flat tables and not like the structure you have above. Will there be multiple products and years? Can you share a little more on the data? It seems you're looking at PowerQuery to solve a presentation ask where Excel formulas maybe all that is needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. While it's true that there will be more years and products, for now, I plan to break down the problem into smaller parts. I will explore the possibility of representing this Excel table in Power Query. I've been assigned this task in Power Query, and the origin table is sourced from a URL link within Power Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this as a starting table:

| product | flow | indicators\TIME_PERIOD | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 71 | 1 | QUANTITY_IN_100KG | 5630860 |
| 71 | 1 | VALUE_IN_EUROS | 35176720 |
| 71 | 2 | QUANTITY_IN_100KG | 8328942 |
| 71 | 2 | VALUE_IN_EUROS | 52490848 |

In PowerQuery, you will need to add a new Custom Column for "time" taking the last column name for the value (eg 2020). Then Pivot Column on `indicators\TIME_PERIOD` and `2020` (ie the previous last column).

This will give you a table like so:

| product | flow | time | QUANTITY_IN_100KG | VALUE_IN_EUROS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 71 | 1 | 2020 | 5630860 | 35176720 |
| 71 | 2 | 2020 | 8328942 | 52490848 |

Here's the full PowerQuery of the above:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"product", Int64.Type}, {"flow", Int64.Type}, {"indicators\TIME_PERIOD", type text}, {"2020", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "time", each List.Last(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")), type text),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[#"indicators\TIME_PERIOD"]), "indicators\TIME_PERIOD", List.Last(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")))
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

I would recommend leaving the structure like this, as you can then add (append) other similar tables together, to give you the one table of data.

Regarding the presentation, again I would recommend tackling this in Excel and not PowerQuery. Keep your PowerQuery table as above, then once loaded in Excel, your can add a reference to the `product` column and then hide that column.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your help! It was really helpful :) Thanks

Comment: Super. Please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.